# Creating DropDown menu C# with SQL DB Tables

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I need your help with something I am working on.

It's very simple, but it has been bugging me.

I am creating a ComboBox[DropDown Menu] in a WPF application and I want to fill it with all the current Tables I have in my DB.

This is what I'm struggling to do:
When I click on the ComboBox it will show all the available tables in the DataBase. Then when I click on one of them it will show the information that is contained within the selected table in a DataGrid I've placed below the menu.

[image: My Application]

And here Is the code I am using when the ComboBox opens:

```
private void tableComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';", db.connection);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        foreach(DataRow row in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            tableComboBox.Items.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

I've already looked and tried some different approaches but non of them work.
And I've tried to show the Content of a Table in the DataGrid but I got stuck again.

Please fellow coders. Help this newbie over here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I quickly came up with.

1. remove the tableComboBox_DropDownOpened event.
2. add the event comboBox_SelectionChange
3. Change your db connection string, names of the combobox and  dataGrid to match yours.

Here is the code below, I moved the loadCombo() below your initialize to make it simple.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here");

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        loadCombo();
    }

    private void loadCombo()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';", db);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(row[0]);
        }
    }

    private DataTable loadDataGrid(String inTableName )
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '"+ inTableName + "';", db);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
    private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = e.AddedItems[0].ToString(); ;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = loadDataGrid(text).DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

I have updated your code below. Paste this in a give it a shot.  I am not sure what is happening with the create buttons but lets see if we can fix the combobox and datagrid.  I added some comments in the code to help explain my rational.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DatabaseManagement
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Database db = new Database();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add the loadCombo back
        loadCombo();
        // comment this out until you get the desired functionality  
        //TableCreateGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void createButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        // I am not sure what you are doing here -  
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column3TextBox.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(column4TextBox.Text))
            {
                db.CreateTable(tableTextBox.Text, column1TextBox.Text, column2TextBox.Text);

                informationBlock.Text = db.infoBoxString;
            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column4TextBox.Text))
            {
                db.CreateTable(tableTextBox.Text, column1TextBox.Text, column2TextBox.Text, column3TextBox.Text);

                informationBlock.Text = db.infoBoxString;
            }

            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column3TextBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(column4TextBox.Text))
            {
                db.CreateTable(tableTextBox.Text, column1TextBox.Text, column2TextBox.Text, column3TextBox.Text, column4TextBox.Text);

                informationBlock.Text = db.infoBoxString;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            informationBlock.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Connect();
        informationBlock.Text = db.infoBoxString;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        db.Close();
        informationBlock.Text = db.infoBoxString;
    }

    private void loadCombo()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';", db.connection);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            tableComboBox.Items.Add(row[0]);
        }
    }

    private DataTable loadDataGrid(String inTableName)
    {
        //  Here you need to specify the columns you want in the TableCreateGrid
        //  example  this just will show the COLUMN NAME,DATA TYPE, CHARACTER MAXIMUM LENGTH and so on
        //  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + inTableName + "';", db.connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + inTableName + "';", db.connection);

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        return dataSet.Tables[0];
    }

    private void tableComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //loadCombo();
        // dont need since this is loaded on Initialize
    }

    private void tableComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  tableComboBox.Items.Clear();
      // dont need since this will clear all the items in the tableComboBox
    }

    private void tableComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string text = e.AddedItems[0].ToString(); ;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = loadDataGrid(e.AddedItems[0].ToString()).DefaultView;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            informationBlock.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Although it works in a way, after I changed few things, there is still one problem Doa Ink. First thing I noticed is that it doesn't load the data correctly. Here is the image:

http://imgur.com/U8jCFCZ

When I select an item, the ComboBox goes to its default stage with no item selected.

Yes It does show the table in the dataGrid but not as it was intended as you can see in the images below.

I've tried several corrections on my own but none of them worked out.

Here is the full code:

http://www.codesend.com/view/079261ba7c6be8bb8ceae6debc56d30b/

Thanks again for your time Doa

Answer (score 0):

> This is a code to store disply name and value in combobox

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var Header = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        List<string> LV = ListHeader();
        foreach (var listOut in LV)
        {
            Header.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(listOut, "val"+listOut));
        }
        tableComboBox.DataSource = Header;
        tableComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
        tableComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
    }


public List<string> ListHeader()
{
    List<string> list = new List<String>();

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = db.connection;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';";

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

          for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
          {
            list.Add(reader.GetName(i));
          }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Get Header",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

You can get the combobox value like this :

> Console.WriteLine(((KeyValuePair)tableComboBox.SelectedItem).Value.ToString());

Or you only want to get a display name :

> tableComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()